# tabulator setData() and setColumn() performance

Tags: reactjs, tabulator

I have React component that instantiates a tabulator table.
Everything is functional, but there is a performance issue.

My React component is used to display different modestly-sized data sets. When the React component is first created, an initial data set is loaded via an initial table.setData() call. In response to component property changes, different data sets can be loaded via subsequent table.setData() calls.

The first setData() call is fast, but subsequent setData() calls are very slow.

Here are some examples of the performance differences when loading the **SAME** data set.

- first call: 200ms, subsequent call: 1751ms
- first call: 991ms, subsequent call: 3908ms

Please note that when changing a data set, I call both setColumns() & setData().
The setColumns() has a similar performance issue as well.

Is there something I can do "reset" the table so that the performance is similar to the initial setData() and setColumns() calls?

I can't provide the actual source code, but here are the salient points:

```
componentDidMount() {
  this.tableInst = new Tabulator(this.tableRef, {
    layout: "fitData",
    columns: [],
    data: [],
  });
  this.updateTableData();
}

componentDidUpdate() {
  this.updateTableData();
}

updateTableData = () => {
  // Calculate new content in tableColumns & tableData vars
  this.tableInst.setColumns(tableColumns);
  this.tableInst.setDatas(tableData);
}
```

Thanks much!

Answer (score 0):

I originally quantified the performance issue by instrumenting my code with performance.now() & console.log() messages.

I only see my original performance issue when the Chrome debugger is open. When I close the debugger, the tables perform as expected. This makes no sense to me, as there is little output generated in the console. Thought I'd mention in case other run into similar issues.

Comment: This is probably just related to having the devtools open in general.  Here is a related question.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47466794/does-opening-browser-developer-tools-affect-application-performance.